# Virtualbox -- configuring two VMs to talk to each other / host and internet

Tags: networking, virtualbox, nat, loopback

Host: Windows 7 running lastest VBox + Extension pack

Vm1: lubuntu 3.10
Vm2: Ubuntu server 12.04.3

Problem: Can't get VMs talk/ping each other AND ping the internet at the same time

NAT: VMs have same IP, using ping/ssh is like checking connectivity/connecting to self, lol; can ping internet, can't ping each other

Bridged: VMs get unique IP; can ping each other, not the internet

Host-only: VMs get unique IP; can ping each other; not the internet

Internal network:

intnet, needs to be defined/added to windows 7, however, window 7 not accepting VBOXMANAGE add command, giving errors. VMs wait for network configuration, another 60 seconds and start without a network.

What else can I do? 
Change VM to use NAT Network, generic driver... ??? 
edit /etc/network/interfaces? 
change route? 
use squid?

Following Lubuntu Networking Message pops up in Lunbutu GUI:

network service discovery disabled

your cuurent network has a .local domain which is not recommended and incompatible with the avahi network service discovery the service has been disabled.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Quite clearly this is not a programming question. Voting to close.

Comment: My VirtualBox VMs all run bridged, and all get to the internet.  (Using a Windows 7 host.) I just run these one at a time, though and have no reason for them to be aware of each other.)

Comment: Thanks, Mike. I ended up adding another NIC, one with NAT for internet and one with host-only for internal network.

Answer (score 0):

Refresh your MAC address using Virtual Box machine settings and remove the kernel’s networking interface rules file so that it can be regenerated:

```
sudo rm -f /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

sudo reboot

It will work for your clone VM.